# Retrieiving domain object instances as a Map

Tags: hibernate, grails, hql

I wonder if there is a way to retreive domain instances as a Map where the key is the id of the domain object.

more specific i would like to do `myDomainObject.list()` to return a Map instead of a List.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this method easily in your domain class, for example:

```
class Person {

   String name

   static Map<Long, Person> mapAll() {
      def map = [:]
      list().each { map[it.id] = it }
      map      
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe a built in function existed. but this is a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't the only place you need it, you could also use Burts code to extend eiter domain classes or the map itself via the [ExpandoMetaClass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass).

This would centralize the functionality and keep your domain classes clean.